# C++ Memory Corruption When Using String Literals

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a newcomer to C++ and have written a small program to learn more about OOD and polymorphism.

In summary I have a base class (`WeeklyCompCalculator`) containing a single member variable (`string description`) that is passed in via a constructor call in the derived class (`FixedCompCalculator`).

When I initialize the base class with a `const string` (FIXED_SCHEME) everything works fine:

```
FixedCompCalculator::FixedCompCalculator() : WeeklyCompCalculator(FIXED_SCHEME) {}
```

[image]

However, when I attempt to initialize with a string literal, the description member is corrupted:

```
FixedCompCalculator::FixedCompCalculator() : WeeklyCompCalculator("$600 Weekly") {}
```

[image]

I have included the relevant bits of code below. An interesting observation is that if I modify `shoe_comp.cpp` to use raw pointers instead of shared_ptrs, the issue goes away.

comp_calculator.h

```
namespace ShoeCompUtil {
  const string FIXED_SCHEME = "$600 Weekly";
  class WeeklyCompCalculator {
  public:
    WeeklyCompCalculator(const string&);
    virtual ~WeeklyCompCalculator();
    virtual double calculate( const int shoePrice, const int weeklyHours, const int weeklyUnits ) const = 0;
    string getDescription() const;
  private:
    const string& description;
  };

  class FixedCompCalculator : public WeeklyCompCalculator {
  public:
    FixedCompCalculator();
    virtual double calculate( const int shoePrice, const int weeklyHours, const int weeklyUnits ) const;
  };
};
```

comp_calculator.cpp

```
WeeklyCompCalculator::WeeklyCompCalculator(const string& descr): description{descr} {}
WeeklyCompCalculator::~WeeklyCompCalculator(){}
string WeeklyCompCalculator::getDescription() const {
  const string descr{description};
  return descr;
}

FixedCompCalculator::FixedCompCalculator() : WeeklyCompCalculator("$600 Weekly") {}
double FixedCompCalculator::calculate( const int shoePrice, const int weeklyHours, const int weeklyUnits ) const 
{ 
  return 600; 
}
```

shoe_comp.cpp

```
cout << "Computing best compensation scheme given shoe_price = " << shoePrice << ", weeklyHours = " << weeklyHours << ", weeklyUnits = " << weeklyUnits << endl;
vector<shared_ptr<WeeklyCompCalculator>> calculators { make_shared<FixedCompCalculator>(), make_shared<HybridCompCalculator>(), make_shared<CommissionCompCalculator>() };
double maxComp = -1;
string maxDescr = "";
for( const shared_ptr<WeeklyCompCalculator>& calc : calculators ){
  double compHere = calc->calculate( shoePrice, weeklyHours, weeklyUnits );
  if( compHere > maxComp ){
    maxComp = compHere;
    maxDescr = calc->getDescription();
  }
}
cout << "Optimal compensation scheme is " << maxDescr << ", weekly comp = " << maxComp << endl;
```

Comment: `WeeklyCompCalculator::description` is a reference to a `string`. If that string disappears your reference becomes invalid. `FIXED_SCHEME` basically stays alive until the program ends. `"$600 Weekly"` becomes a temporary that disappears at the end of the constructor, leaving you with a dangling reference. You probably want to make `WeeklyCompCalculator::description` a real `string` and not a reference.

Comment: Please don't post text as images, copy and paste them into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derived class constructor passes a string literal to the base class:

```
FixedCompCalculator::FixedCompCalculator() : WeeklyCompCalculator("$600 Weekly")
```

The base class's constructor takes a `const std::string &` as a parameter to its constructor.

```
WeeklyCompCalculator(const string&);
```

Because your parameter is actually a string literal, a ***temporary*** `std::string` object gets constructed, and a reference to it gets passed to the base class's constructor.

The base class constructor takes the reference it receives, as its argument, and saves it as its class's member.

Because the class member ends up being a reference to a temporary object, as soon as the derived class finishes constructing (slightly earlier, to be pedantically correct, but it's not relevant here), the temporary object gets destroyed, and the base class ends up with a reference to a destroyed object, and using this reference from that point on results in undefined behavior.

The simplest fix is to have `WeeklyCompCalculator`'s class member to be an explicit object instance, and not a reference:

```
  private:
    const string description;
  };
```

Now, the `description` class member is guaranteed to exist as long as the instance of its class exists.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was an extremely clear and instructive explanation.